# SQL/Spark: get condition with group and null values

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I would need to get an if statement that
groups by a date field (named VALIDTO)
and returns just one null value if there are any nulls in the group
or returns the maximun in case there are not nulls in the group.
This should work but it is very tricky as MAX, MIN and COUNT
ignore null values:

```
test = sql_context.sql(""" select field1, field2, 
                                  if(MIN(VALIDTO) is null, null, MAX(VALIDTO)) as VALIDTO
                                  from test_table
                                """)
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether there are nulls by getting the maximum of `VALIDTO is null` in that group:

```
select 
    field1, field2, 
    case when max(VALIDTO is null) = False then max(VALIDTO) end as VALIDTO
from test_table
group by field1, field2
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I think you want an aggregation function on `validto` to return `NULL` if *any* values are `NULL`.  If so,  you can use `case`:

```
(case when count(*) = count(validTo) then max(validTo)
 end)
```